# Declare section where Electron must search text (Vue)

Tags: vue.js, electron

I using in my application function `findInPage`. In main.js I have:

```
  ipcMain.on('search-text', (event, arg) => {    
    mainWindow.webContents.findInPage(arg);
  });
```

and in component:

```
searchText(text){
    ipcRenderer.send('search-text', text);
}
```

In application I have two component `Menu.vue` and `News.vue`.

When user search text in the search engine Electron searching in ALL applications.

For example:

In Menu.vue I have:

- Home
- Contact

In News.vue I have:

"Woman back to home."

When user search word "Home" Electron selected home word in Menu and in News.

How can I declare where Electron must search ?

Comment: i am not sure i understand your issue - `webContents` is where you search. A `findInVueComponent` has to be written - i think. `findInPage(vueComponentStartIdentifier) < findInPage(arg) < findInPage(vueComponentEndIdentifier)`

Comment: @Estradiaz I must declare component where function `findInPage` should search

Comment: electron will search in webContents - it does not care about what information possibly is in the webContents - it will search for strings from top or from bottom. ... either prepare webContents accordingly or interpret search results.

Comment: I'm not sure search strings from top or from bottom. For example in program Visual Studio Code can search only in the code not in menu